# how to create registry key through java program?

Tags: java, registry

I want to create registry key through java program to add the jar file in the start up.

```
RegistryKey r=new RegistryKey(RootKey.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run");
        r.createSubkey("sample");
```

But i got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey.testInitialized()V
        at ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey.testInitialized(Native Method)
```

How can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: hey does it work with 65bit OS?
if not then is there any alternative?

Comment: Somebody has posted a link to a 64-bit build of the DLL at http://sourceforge.net/p/jregistrykey/support-requests/17/, though I cannot make it work off-hand - still get the above exception. If anybody else can make it work, let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `JRegistryKey.jar` in the library.
Then copy and paste `JRegistryKey.dll` in my project.

After that I run the same program ,The registry key is created successfully.

```
RegistryKey r=new RegistryKey(RootKey.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
        RegistryValue v=new RegistryValue("name or the registrykey",ValueType.REG_SZ,"my jar file path");
        r.setValue(v);
```

Answer (score 7):

From [the Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html):

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.

You wouldn't be on a win **64** OS by any chance?

If not, the [manual for jreg mentions](http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/sourceforge/j/project/jr/jregistrykey/manual/original/jreg_key.pdf):

> `jRegistryKey` is a `JNI` library. To use `jRegistryKey`, the following files are required:
>
> - `jRegistryKey.jar`
> - `jRegistryKey.dll`
>
> jRegistryKey.jar is the Java™ Archive (JAR) file containing the packaged Java™ class files, whereas jRegistryKey.dll is a Windows® dyanmically linked library (DLL) that contains the native (C/C++) code required to access the registry.
>
> **`jRegistryKey.jar` must be included in the `CLASSPATH` available to the Java™ Virtual Machine (JVM);**
>
> **`jRegistryKey.dll` must be located in a directory included in the Windows® PATH environment variable or `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`'s will be generated**

Comment: I added JRegistryKey.jar.But Where i have to add the JRegistryKey.dll?

Comment: @Arivu2020: anywhere to one of the path referenced by your environment variable %PATH%, or you can add the path of that dll to your Windows %PATH%. See http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm or http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm or http://www.brightrev.com/how-to/windows/35-add-a-utilities-directory-to-your-pc.html?start=1

Comment: just add the dll file in my project is enough to run. Thank you very much VonC

Answer (score 2):

Adding jregistrykey.dll in my project didn't work for me.
I included this block in my class and it worked.

```
static {
    System.load("path\\to\\jregistrykey.dll");
}
```