# Program works perfectly in Netbeans but the zar file does not invoking registry

Tags: java, native, netbeans-8, registrykey

My program is working in Netbeans 8.2 perfectly but after clean and build, when i run the ZAR file,it throws exception at below line
            RegistryKey.initialize("jRegistryKey.dll");
and the code is

```
System.load(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\jRegistryKey.dll");
             RegistryKey.initialize("jRegistryKey.dll");
             RegistryKey key = new RegistryKey(RootKey.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software");
        for (Iterator<RegistryKey> subkeys = key.subkeys(); subkeys.hasNext();) {
            RegistryKey subkey = subkeys.next();
            if(subkey.getName().trim().startsWith("MySQL"))
             { installed=1;
               break;
             }
           }
         if(installed==1) 
           {...some code
           .......}<br.
```

and the exception is

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey.testInitialized()V
    at ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey.testInitialized(Native Method)
    at ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey.initialize(RegistryKey.java:312)
```

and more...
Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this can help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627446/how-to-create-registry-key-through-java-program

Comment: Btw: There's no such thing as a **ZAR** file. I assume you mean a **Jar** file ??

Comment: sorry...its jar.    i have spent one week but no solution...i have done everything including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627446/how-to-create-registry-key-through-java-program